# Salesforce MyTrailhead app vs community app

Tags: community, trailhead

we have users who will be using MyTrailhead but also Communities. Most of the time, they will be using their mobile. Would they need 2 separate apps (one for myTrailhead and one for Communities) or just one ?

Comment: Regarding the users who are using Communities, are they access it via the traditional Salesforce mobile app, or are you using [Mobile Publisher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItDxOR99s7s) to publish your own branded mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Trailhead mobile app, which is called `Trailhead GO` is different to the traditional Salesforce mobile app. So they will need two mobile apps.